# jQuery .load() won't doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

jQuery describes a certain application for the `.load()`

`$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');`

*"When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded."*

To test this out, I tried to get the inner HTML of the Google Search button. The id for the Google Search button is 'gbqfsa'.

So I wrote this:

`$('#externalcontent').load('http://www.google.com #gbqfsa');`

However, it doesn't seem to work. I made a full example of the problem in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGqZP/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope! You cannot use JavaScript to load a page from a remote website. This violates [Same Domain Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules).

Comment: Thanks! Well the final usage for this will be on the same domain, so I won't have this problem.

Comment: Do you know if it would still work if both pages are on the same domain but different sub-domains? The wikipedia article you linked doesn't detail that.

Comment: subdomains will not work. https will not work either. It can't even be the same machine with different hostnames (e.g. localhost vs 127.0.0.1). EVERYTHING needs to be identical.

Comment: Wow. Well that poses a problem... :/